# Python script to download specific files from FTP and update the download directory

Tags: python

I need some help in order to create a script to download multiple .csv files from FTP every 24 hours, ignoring the old files and to continue downloading the new ones to keep an update. I'm having trouble writing the pattern because the name of the files vary from 01150728.csv, 01150904.csv to 02xxxxxx.csv, 03xxxxx.csv and currently it reached 30151007.csv.
The script that I'm currently using downloads all the files but I need a command line in order to do what I described earlier.

```
from ftplib import FTP
import sys
import ftplib
import os
import fnmatch
os.chdir(r'______________') # Directory where the files need to be downloaded
ftp=ftplib.FTP('xxxxxxxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxxx') # ftp host info
ftp.cwd('______')
filematch='*csv'
for filename in ftp.nlst(filematch):
    fhandle=open(filename, 'wb')
    print 'Getting ' + filename
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ filename, fhandle.write)
    fhandle.close()


ftp.quit()
```

Answer (score 3):

You should keep a list or set of the files already fetched. The following assumes you run the code once and don't exit.

```
from ftplib import FTP
import sys
import ftplib
import os
import fnmatch
os.chdir(r'______________') # Directory where the files need to be downloaded
ftp=ftplib.FTP('xxxxxxxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxxx') # ftp host info
ftp.cwd('______')
filematch='*csv'
import time

downloaded = []

while True:  # runs forever
    skipped = 0

    for filename in ftp.nlst(filematch):
        if filename not in downloaded:
            fhandle=open(filename, 'wb')
            print 'Getting ' + filename
            ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ filename, fhandle.write)
            fhandle.close()
            downloaded.append(filename)
        else:
            skipped += 1

    print 'Downloaded %s, skipped %d files' % (downloaded[-1], skipped)
    time.sleep(24*60*60)  # sleep 24 hours after finishing last download

ftp.quit()
```

If you run the script each day, omit the while loop and use pickle or simply write the list/set in a file, and load it at the start of the script.

Comment: Thank you, it improved the script, but when I run it, instead of downloading the most recent files, it only downloads the same .csv file from FTP which was last modified two months ago even if I already have that file in the directory.

Comment: This is the type of solution that I wish I could upvote more than once. Downloading a csv from an ftp server was turning into a much bigger process than I expected. It's funny how on one day you can read through 30 implementations of a task and not find the solution you are looking for. Then the next day, all it takes is the 2nd link to find the solution that perfectly fits your needs. Thank you!

Comment: Hi! Does anyone knows where to find the same algorythm but for sftp?

Comment: Hi just wondering what is `while True:  skipped = 0` used for?

Comment: and is there a way to create a 'tmp' folder in the directory to store all the downloaded files?